# Unable to dismiss a UIPopover from another class

Tags: ios6, uipopovercontroller

I have a iPad app, created in XCode 4.6.3, iOS 6.2, ARC and Storyboards.

I create a UIPopover programmatically in SubViewData.m.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPopoverController *popover;

    //  make rectangle to attach popover
    CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake( touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y, 110, 1);  //  0 height puts arrow on exact touch point

    //  get addressability to storyboard ViewController
    UIViewController *popoverMainView = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"menuView"];

    popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverMainView];
                            [popover presentPopoverFromRect:rectangle inView:self
                            permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

I set notifications in another class (QuickAppointment.m) when a UIButton in the popover has been tapped.  I get the notification and issue this code from CalendarViewController.m :

```
SubViewData *svd = [[SubViewData alloc] init];
[svd.popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
```

Nothing happens!  I don't understand why not... so, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the code you are writing:

```
SubViewData *svd = [[SubViewData alloc] init];
```

This creates a **completely new and different** instance of SubViewData, and not the one that is displaying the popover.

Comment: I tried putting the dismiss code in SubViewData.m, but nothing happens then either... where should the code to dismiss be?  and how get to the instance of SubViewData without creating a new one? (I thought I was doing it the right way, but apparently not)..

Comment: Since I don't know how or what you are adding to SubViewData.m I can't help with that. As for getting the correct instance - you do this the same way that you get instances for anything; by passing a reference to the object that will call it's methods.

Comment: I tried that (passing a reference)... this is what I used:    
    [SubViewData.popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    
It doesn't know what _popover_ is...    

Can you give me a doc where I can do some reading on this whole instantiate thing?  I would really, really appreciate it.  I'm struggling with this...

Comment: Are you sure this isn't giving you compiler warnings? It looks like you are asking for properties on a class not an object. Does your SubViewData object have a property called `popover`? Have you set it to be the popover controller?

Comment: Yes... SubViewData has an object called popover (see original question above) and it is set to be the popover controller (same code).

Comment: Fair enough. And how are you passing the reference the view controller to the object that is trying to dismiss the view controller?

Comment: The code where I did the alloc-init, which is not correct (I have a method which will do the dismissing of the popover, but needs to go in the right place). So I was thinking there has to be a another way.  I use alloc-init all over the place and it seemed to work... what a mess!

Comment: I finally figured it out!   
`SubViewData *svd = (SubViewData *) self.subViewData;
    [svd.popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];`

Comment: Why not just `[self.subViewData.popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];`?

Comment: Uh... I wasn't aware that I could do it... (there is SOooo much to learn about Obj-C, and I don't have the time now).  And being an old noob, I like the way I did it because it's self documenting, if you know what I mean (at least to me)... thanks again for your help; as always, I appreciate it.